# How to recursively move a package between source folders in Eclipse and update CVS?

Tags: java, eclipse, version-control, cvs

So I needed to move a large package from the default `src` to another source folder called `test`.  I did this by simply moving the directory on the file system then refreshing Eclipse.  Everything went fine as far as Eclipse is concerned.

However, the problem is copying did not change the CVS metadata that was in those folders.  Now every time I synchronize with CVS it will switch between wanting to update or remove all the files in the package.

**How do you recursively move a package without causing CVS problems?**  Again, this has no effect on the package names, just on the source folder being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done directory moves many times in Eclipse without issue.  Do the move within Eclipse itself (not in your external filesystem) and the CVS plugin will keep track of all the moves, so the next time you synch with your repository, it will show what things have been deleted (marked with minus signs in the GUI) and what has been added (marked with plus signs in the GUI).  Note that you will lose your history in the Eclipse GUI for the moved files, which will be back at v1.1.

Comment: In Eclipse how do you move a package (and all subpackages) between source folders?

Comment: In the Project Explorer, right-click on the package, then choose Refactor-Move. In the Move dialog, choose the new source folder and click OK.  Eclipse determines all the changes, alerts you to any issues, and does everything else.

Comment: I don't think this recursively moves subpackages however.

Comment: You can select as many packages and sub-packages as you want, then all get moved

Comment: Can't believe I did not know that.  Thanks!

Comment: You must use a flat package presentation (not hierarchical, that's the trick) to select all subpackages. Than move or copy-paste to new source-folder.

Comment: chrise's answer is the real answer!! I've struggled with this for years! Never knew I had to switch back to flat presentation to be able to copy-paste packages with full subpackages!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it seems that all I needed to do was manually move the package folder then do

```
find . -name CVS -type d | xargs rm -rf
```

in the folder to remove all the CVS information before refreshing and synchronizing with CVS.

Comment: I think this is about the best you can do in CVS. For the extremely paranoid, you may want to add in `-type d` into the find command.

Comment: Actually, rethinking this, I believe you could also move the directory on the server, which will preserve the history for the individual files.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, although I would be afraid to mess with the repository on the server itself.